# dnsmasq address forwarding to host name

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I need to forward dns requests using the wildcard address=/#/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx method.

This works fine when the ip address of the forwarded server is static, but the ip address is dynamic and I can only therefore use it's hostname.

This will work to forward all requests

```
address=/#/some.server.ip.address
```

Of course this does not as it must use an ip address ?

```
address=/#/hostname
```

is there a way of doing this using dnsmasq alone ?